SPL Token Metadata Initialization Error - Transaction Simulation Failed
I am trying the SPL Token Program to configure the metadata for the token deployed on DevNet. I have validated the token mint address. It is displaying the following error. Could you please help to understand this issue.
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xc", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(1, Custom(12))), logs: Some(["Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]", "Program log: Error: Invalid instruction", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 863 of 399850 compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: custom program error: 0xc"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(1013), return_data: None }) }) })

Looks like you are trying to initialize token meta data with the old token program.
Tokenkeg... is the old program.
The Token Extensions program has the programID TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb and is a superset of the original functionality provided by the Token Program at TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA.
So in your case you probably need to add the token program id.
Probably something like this:
spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --enable-metadata
spl-token initialize-metadata EBF22st7gRqvKtEYW2WomsHUsNrjtPcZvpDAnh6W7Ugu Snail SLUG https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-examples
spl-token create-account EBF22st7gRqvKtEYW2WomsHUsNrjtPcZvpDAnh6W7Ugu
spl-token mint EBF22st7gRqvKtEYW2WomsHUsNrjtPcZvpDAnh6W7Ugu 100
spl-token update-metadata EBF22st7gRqvKtEYW2WomsHUsNrjtPcZvpDAnh6W7Ugu Snail SLUG https://shdw-drive.genesysgo.net/AzjHvXgqUJortnr5fXDG2aPkp2PfFMvu4Egr57fdiite/PirateCoinMeta
```

